# JSON. Не получается прочитать массив

Tags: java, json

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "277",
           "short_name" : "277",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
           "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings",
           "short_name" : "Kings",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.714232,
           "lng" : -73.9612889
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
              "lng" : -73.9599399197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
              "lng" : -73.96263788029151
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },

 // ... Additional results truncated in this example[] ...

 ],
"status" : "OK"
 }
```

Из него надо прочитать `formatted_address`. Но проблема в том, что их несколько. В примере не вставлял. Вот как добрать и прочитать его? Пробую так:

```
 JSONArray fa = (JSONArray) resultJson.get("results");

  Iterator i = fa.iterator();

  while (i.hasNext()) {
     JSONObject adr = (JSONObject) i.next();
     String title = (String) adr.get("formatted_address");
     System.out.println(title);
  }
```

В итоге читаются все `formatted_address`. А мне надо только первое. Как это реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: первое в первом элементе массива results? Ну так уберите while

Comment: Спасибо. Это же надо. и не подумал. А как можно добраться до остальных? К примеру к "address_components"  и прочитать "long_name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратитесь просто по индексу, зачем вы итерируетесь по всему массиву?

```
// Получаем весь массив
JSONArray results = resultJson.getJSONArray("results");

// По индексу 0 получаем первый элемент
JSONObject firstResult = results.getJSONObject(0);

// Достаём нужное поле
String formattedAddress = firstResult.getString("formatted_address");
```

Если массив `results` может быть пуст, просто добавьте проверку на размер до получения элемента по индексу.

Получаем другие данные:

```
// Получаем массив 'address_components' 
// из первого элемента из массива 'results'
JSONArray addressComponents = firstResult.getJSONArray("address_components");

// Получаем по индексу первый элемент этого массива
JSONObject firstAddressComponent = addressComponents.getJSONObject(0);

// Получаем нужное поле
String longName = firstAddressComponent.getString("long_name");
```